# Queuing YouTube Videos

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I want to know how to add selected YouTube videos to a temporary playlist / playing queue?
I have an option where user have to select what all videos to be included in the playing queue.

> Click on the ADD icon (black background box) and that selected video will be displayed in the purple background and it also has to be included in the playlist/Queue.

[image]

I am able to add the videos in the purple box but unable to add them in the queue.

I tried using this code

```
player.cuePlaylist({
    list:  ["83uA6kS_6LE", "RVYU9Be2RtA", "DkQRcjKTqiU", "5NUZtQRgLSQ"]  //array of videos ID
});
```

After that when currently playing video ends I tried to play next video using

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
if(event.data==0){     //when video ends event.data becomes 0 
      player.nextVideo();
}
```

But it neither do anything nor shows any error in the console.
I even tried replacing `player.nextVideo();` with `player.playVideo();` then instead of starting next video it re-plays the current one.

I tried looking for it in the YouTube documentation but couldn't find anything
https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Queueing_Functions

**EDIT 1**
TRIED with 
`cueVideoById();` `loadVideoById();`
But not working. 

I would **really appreciate** if you guys can **provide me an answer** or a way to **reach the correct audience** for this question.

Comment: Can you provide the error logs?

Comment: @abielita its not showing any error in the console

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you have a typo in your call to cuePlaylist. The argument is "playlist" and not "list". Try this:

```
player.cuePlaylist({
    playlist:  ["83uA6kS_6LE", "RVYU9Be2RtA", "DkQRcjKTqiU", "5NUZtQRgLSQ"]
});
```